# Cannot get contexts with "agent.context.get()" from Google Assistant request

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-assistant

The method **agent.context.get('context-name')** return **undefined** when i receive a request from *Google Assistant* on my Node.js server. (I'm using the package "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.0")

The same method **works fine** when the request comes from *Dialogflow*.

Watching the request, I can see that it's correctly filled when it comes from Dialogflow (the context that I set are present), while it returns the context "-" when the request comes from Google Assistant (like if no contexts are present).

It worked perfectly until a few days ago, but now it doesn't work anymore.

Any suggest?